# Exclude paths with duplicated nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher, data-modeling, flightpath

In my flight modelization, I would like to search for path with 1 stop which is equivalent in the graph to have a 4 hops relationships from the source to the destination. When searching the path with :

```
     match (s:Airport{airportName:'CAN'}),
     (d:Airport{airportName:'ICN'})
     with s,d 
     match p = (s)<-[*4]->(d)
     return  nodes(p), relationships(p)
```

But this also give me path with airport node that are visited twice, like this : [airport node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7Cnx.png)

So my question is, how to exclude paths which contains duplicated nodes ?
How to detect whether there is a duplicated node within a path ?

Thank you !

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_graph_algorithms_work_in_progress), you can try using `apoc.algo.allSimplePaths()`, which will not contain any loops back to a previously visited node in the path.

```
 match (s:Airport{airportName:'CAN'}),
  (d:Airport{airportName:'ICN'})
 call apoc.algo.allSimplePaths(s, d, '', 4) yield path
 return  nodes(path), relationships(path)
```